# Unable to load same url with ng-include and $templateCache consecutively

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

main jsp:

```
 <div>
    <jsp:include page='/jsp/pnPanel.jsp'/>                       
 </div>
```

pnPanel.jsp:

```
<div id="pnApp" ng-controller="pnController">    
    <div>
        <a  href="#" ng-click="loadPopup('cc');">
            <font size="2" color="#cc6600">
            <b>CC:</b>
            </font>
        </a>
    </div>
    <ng-include src="popupurl"></ng-include>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    angular.element(document.getElementById("pnApp")).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("pnApp"), ["pnApp"]);
        });

    var pnApp= angular.module('pnApp', []);

    pnApp.config(function($controllerProvider, $provide, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $httpProvider) {

        // to keep the older references.
        pnApp._controller = pnApp.controller;
        pnApp._service = pnApp.service;
        pnApp._factory = pnApp.factory;
        pnApp._value = pnApp.value;
        pnApp._directive = pnApp.directive;

        // Lazy loading for controller.
        pnApp.controller = function(name, constructor) {

            $controllerProvider.register(name, constructor);
            return(this);

        };

        // Lazy loading for service.
        pnApp.service = function(name, constructor) {

            $provide.service(name, constructor);
            return(this);

        };

        // Lazy loading for factory.
        pnApp.factory = function(name, factory) {

            $provide.factory(name, factory);
            return(this);

        };

        // Lazy loading for value.
        pnApp.value = function(name, value) {

            $provide.value(name, value);
            return(this);

        };

        // Lazy loading for directive.
        pnApp.directive = function(name, factory) {

            $compileProvider.directive(name, factory);
            return(this);

        };

        // Lazy loading for filter
        pnApp.filter = function(name, filter) {

            $filterProvider.register(name, filter);
            return(this);

        };

        //initialize get if not there
        if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
        }

        //disable IE ajax request caching
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';

    });

    pnApp.controller('pnController', function($scope) {
        $scope.loadPopup = function(pnSectionName) {
                $scope.popupurl = "";                      
                url = getUrl(pnSectionName);
                $scope.popupurl = url;
            };

    };
</script>
```

On call of **$scope.loadPopup** method the url for **ng-include** is populated and jsp call occurs which has its own controller and has included js files required for that jsp call and the modal present in it opens.This jsp has a modal which hides on close.But when I click on the link again **it doesnot make a jsp call again with same url**.I even tried clearing the cache using **$templateCache** as below.But didnot work.

```
pnApp.controller('pnController', function($scope,$templateCache) {
        $scope.loadPopup = function(pnSectionName){                 
                url = getUrl(pnSectionName);
        $templateCache.remove(url);
        $scope.popupurl = "";
                $scope.popupurl = url;
            };

    };
```

But when I append a random number to the url it works.I dont want to append the random number.Why does it not work with **$templateCache.remove(url)**.

Comment: Probably because the template is stored with another key, not `url`. Try to console log `$templateCache.ret(url)`. Does it output your template?

Comment: doesn't appear you are injecting `$templateCache` in controller. Any errors thrown?